# Write a system life saver for ubuntu for restoring broken system to a working state

Tags: linux, ubuntu, system

I am thinking of writing a system life saver application for ubuntu, which can restore system to an earlier state. This could be much useful in situations of system break.
User can create restore point before and then use them to restore their system.
This would be used for packages initially and then later on for restoring previous versions of files,somewhat like system restore functionality in microsoft windows.
Here is the idea page [Idea page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemRestore)

I have gone through some ideas of implementing it like that which is done in windows, by keeping information about the files in the filesystem, the filesystem is intelligent enough to be used for this feature. But we don't have such file system available in linux, one such file system is brtfs but using this will lead to users creating partitions, which will be cumbersome. So I am thinking of a "copy-on-write and save-on-delete" approach. When a restore point is created I will create a new directory for backup like "backup#1" in the restore folder created by application earlier and then create hard links for the files needed to be restored. Now if any file is deleted from its original location I would have its hard link with me which can be used to restore the file, when needed. But this approach doesn't work on modification. For modification I am thinking of creating hooks in the file system (using [redirfs](http://www.redirfs.org/tiki-index.php) ) which will call my attached callbacks which will check for the modifications in various parts of the files. I will keep these all changes in the database and then reverse the changes as soon as a restore is needed.

Please suggest me some efficient approaches for doing this.
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered a Revision Control System? Also, this doesn't feel like a stackoverflow-style question.

Comment: You should look into LVM snapshots.

Comment: @Mel Ok. I think it could be a good idea ,the way git and other svc monitor for changes in the given files, but I doubt its performance when scaled for whole system.
Could you suggest me where should I ask this question

Comment: @caf LVM snapshots is quite a good idea but the problem with that is the space problem, if some method could be there which might require some less space than having a copy of almost most of the files which might not be modified by the user.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a journaling file system.  When you modify the file system, keep the old information around, and a commit trail so that you know what to undo and how. If "users creating partitions" is a problem, sounds to me like you should work around this problem instead.  Why is it a problem?  Don't they create partitions already?  Can't you limit the scope of this to new installations, and do the partitioning in the installer?

Comment: @user517272: I am pretty sure that LVM snapshots do not take up space for the files which are unchanged since the snapshot.

Comment: @tripleee: Ok. I will be using ext4 file system for my application, users would have ubuntu installed on there system with "/" mounted on an ext4 partition. To use brtfs we will need to have "/" mounted on a brtfs file system. This would be a problem I suppose. Could you suggest something to do this using ext4.

Comment: @caf: If thats so it will be really great then, I will look for more details about that. Could you suggest me something to read about the requirements of having such a system, Can logical volumes be used with existing partitions ?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that I would approach this from the ground up.  Change the installer so that `/` is mounted on a file system which has the features you need.  As far as I understand your requirements, this would mean something like `btrfs` or ZFS, or a completely new file system you have designed for this purpose.  Then the rest, as they say, ought to be a simple matter of programming.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments suggested, the LVM snapshot ability provides a good basis for such an undertaking. It would work on a per-partition level and saves only sectors changed in comparison with the current system state. The LVM howto [gives a good overview](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html).

You'll have to set up the system from the very start with LVM, though, and leave sufficient space for snapshots.

Comment: Thanks for helping , I will go through its overview. Actually I cannot have such a method which requires reinstallation of whole system, isn't there a work around by which I can use LVM like in a file ?

Comment: I don't think there is such a high-level approach, but good luck anyway.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for your help, it would be great if you could suggest me any other place I could post my question.